# Deleting Rows from Sections in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having a hard time deleting rows from a section. When I user selects the row I get the indexPath as shown below:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

    // call a method that performs the deletion
}
```

The actual delete method is called when the user presses the delete button

```
            [_groceryItems removeObject:groceryItem];

             [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_selectedIndexPath.row inSection:_selectedIndexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];  <-- THIS LINE BLOWS UP!
```

> Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (3), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

What an I doing wrong?

**UPDATE: Adding Code for the numberOfRowsInSection:**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSArray *groceryItemsInCategory = [self getGroceryItemsByCategoryName:_groceryItemCategories[section] section:section];

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [groceryItemsInCategory count];
}

-(NSArray *) getGroceryItemsByCategoryName:(NSString *) categoryName section:(NSInteger) section {

   return [_groceryItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"groceryItemCategory.title = %@",_groceryItemCategories[section]]];
}
```

[image]

**Adding an Image:**

Comment: Show your code for the `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

Comment: BTW - you can shorten you code for the creating the index path array to just: `@[ _selectedIndexPath ]`.

Comment: Thanks! I have just updated the code in the original question. I have only one row in that section. Should I be deleting or removing the section manually when the row is deleted.

Comment: You also need to post the `numberOfSections` method since the error is telling you that the number of sections doesn't match. If think the problem is that your removed item results in you returning one less section but your code deletes a row, not a section from the table view.

Comment: The item I am deleting from a section is the only item in that section. Once I delete the item the section should not appear since there are no more items in that section.

Comment: Then you need to call `deleteSections` on the table view instead of `deleteRows`.

Comment: But I am not really deleting a section. I am deleting a row in the section. That row is the only row in the section.

Comment: Hi, do you want to delete single row or multiple rows at the same time from the same section. Can you please image of how you are getting delete functionality.

Comment: It can be multiple rows. The rows are deleting when a button in the footer of the UITableView is clicked. I have updated the original post with an image.